# Are there step by step instructions for making a serial terminal work in 16.04?

Tags: command-line, serial-port

I have a serial terminal hooked up via serial to USB cable. It is at device ttyUSB0, I have determined.

I tried `agetty ttyUSB0 vt100` which I was lead to believe would produce something, but nothing happened. It hung until I killed it with `kill`.

I found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto

But it's out of date because of `systemd`.

I also looked here: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html

but I wasn't able to reproduce the steps required to make my serial terminal work at boot.

Someone suggested that for debugging reasons the following command could be run:

```
ps -ef > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

but it told me `Permission denied`.

At one point it was echoing characters I typed to the terminal screen, although `return` wasn't working, but I am no longer able to do that.

Are there straight forward steps I can try to hook up this serial terminal to my computer?

Comment: Have you tried accessing it with `minicom`? I usually use that one if I want to access a serial device.

Comment: @Ziazis I thought that `minicom` was for accessing serial devices that are outputting data to the computer, not the other way around? At least that's the way I've always used it. I can try it.

Comment: It's dual, you input data and receive :-)